# Tensorflow transform each element of a string tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a tensor of strings. Some example strings are as follows.

```
com.abc.display,com.abc.backend,com.xyz.forte,blah
com.pqr,npr.goog
```

I want to do some preprocessing which splits the CSV into its part, then splits each part at the dots and then create multiple strings where one string is a prefix of another. Also, all `blah`s have to be dropped.

For example, given the first string `com.abc.display,com.abc.backend,com.xyz.forte`, it is transformed into an array/list of the following strings.

```
['com', 'com.abc', 'com.abc.display', 'com.abc.backend', 'com.xyz', 'com.xyz.forte']
```

The resulting list has no duplicates (that is why the prefixed strings for `com.abc.backend` didn't show up as those were already included - `com` and `com.abc`).

I wrote the following python function that would do the above given a single CSV string example.

```
def expand_meta(meta):
    expanded_subparts = []
    meta_parts = set([x for x in meta.split(',') if x != 'blah'])
    for part in meta_parts:
        subparts = part.split('.')
        for i in range(len(subparts)+1):
            expanded = '.'.join(subparts[:i])
            if expanded:
                expanded_subparts.append(expanded)
    return list(set(expanded_subparts))
```

Calling this method on the first example

```
expand_meta('com.abc.display,com.abc.backend,com.xyz.forte,blah')
```

returns

```
['com.abc.display',
 'com.abc',
 'com.xyz',
 'com.xyz.forte',
 'com.abc.backend',
 'com']
```

I know that tensorflow has this `map_fn` method. I was hoping to use that to transform each element of the tensor. However, I am getting the following error.

```
File "mypreprocess.py", line 152, in expand_meta
    meta_parts = set([x for x in meta.split(',') if x != 'blah'])
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'split'
```

So, it seems like I can't use a regular python function with `map_fn` since it expects the elements to be `tensor`s. How can I do what I intend to do here?

(My `Tensorflow` version is 1.11.0)

Comment: Is your input data a single comma-separated string, or a tensor with several of those? If it is the second case, what would be the expected output? Because each string would give a different number of results. Also, 1.11.0 is rather old, any chance you can upgrade, even within 1.x? I think 1.12 already introduced some improvements in string functions.

Comment: I wish we could upgrade to 1.15 but it's not up to me. There are efforts toward that but I doubt it would happen in the next few months. So, I'll have to stick with 1.11.

Comment: The input is a tensor with multiple CSV strings. Basically, it comes from a SQL column where the column value can be a string of the type I mentioned in the post. The expected output would be a tensor of a `list of strings`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

# Function to process a single string
def make_splits(s):
    s = tf.convert_to_tensor(s)
    # Split by comma
    split1 = tf.strings.split([s], ',').values
    # Remove blahs
    split1 = tf.boolean_mask(split1, tf.not_equal(split1, 'blah'))
    # Split by period
    split2 = tf.string_split(split1, '.')
    # Get dense split tensor
    split2_dense = tf.sparse.to_dense(split2, default_value='')
    # Accummulated concatenations
    concats = tf.scan(lambda a, b: tf.string_join([a, b], '.'),
                      tf.transpose(split2_dense))
    # Get relevant concatenations
    out = tf.gather_nd(tf.transpose(concats), split2.indices)
    # Remove duplicates
    return tf.unique(out)[0]

# Test
with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    # Individual examples
    print(make_splits('com.abc.display,com.abc.backend,com.xyz.forte,blah').eval())
    # [b'com' b'com.abc' b'com.abc.display' b'com.abc.backend' b'com.xyz'
    #  b'com.xyz.forte']
    print(make_splits('com.pqr,npr.goog').eval())
    # [b'com' b'com.pqr' b'npr' b'npr.goog']

    # Apply to multiple strings with a loop
    data = tf.constant([
        'com.abc.display,com.abc.backend,com.xyz.forte,blah',
        'com.pqr,npr.goog'])
    ta = tf.TensorArray(size=data.shape[0], dtype=tf.string,
                        infer_shape=False, element_shape=[None])
    _, ta = tf.while_loop(
        lambda i, ta: i < tf.shape(data)[0],
        lambda i, ta: (i + 1, ta.write(i, make_splits(data[i]))),
        [0, ta])
    out = ta.concat()
    print(out.eval())
    # [b'com' b'com.abc' b'com.abc.display' b'com.abc.backend' b'com.xyz'
    #  b'com.xyz.forte' b'com' b'com.pqr' b'npr' b'npr.goog']
```

I'm not sure if you want the total results concatenated like that, or maybe you want to apply `tf.unique` to the global result, but in any case the idea is the same.